# Hiding green constraint drag trail in Matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm trying to create a small mobile game using Matter.js. I'm testing a few things with their mobile demo, found here: https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/demo/js/DemoMobile.js

I can't figure out how to hide this green dragging trail that is shown when I drag an object. I tried to do the following:

```
World.add(_world, MouseConstraint.create(_engine, {
    render: {
        visible: false,
        lineWidth: 0,
        strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    }
}));
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
  constraint: {
    render: {
      visible: false
    }
  }
});
```